# Тире или двоеточие при указании специальности

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания следует поставить?

Аспирантура ( ) политические институты и процессы, международные отношения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коль речь идет о специальности, а это действительно так ([НОМЕНКЛАТУРА СПЕЦИАЛЬНОСТЕЙ ПО ПРИСУЖДЕНИЮ УЧЕНЫХ СТЕПЕНЕЙ](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjKsayig7zXAhVFCewKHZFtD1QQFgg1MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.boh.am%2Fdownloadfile.php%3Fid%3D2%26langid%3D2&usg=AOvVaw0NpteNja-UqdBEviK-xUWl)), то предложенные варианты выглядят "коряво". Я бы предложил такой вариант:

**Аспирантура по специальности "Политические институты и процессы, международные отношения".**

Answer (score 1):

В подобных заголовках возможны варианты пунктуационного оформления.

Ср.: Профессия: репортёр и Профессия — репортёр.

[См.: Д.Э. Розенталь.Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php)

Answer (score 1):

**Аспирантура** *(а именно)*: **"Политические институты и процессы, международные отношения"**.

А вообще, судя по названию, это не специальность, а профиль подготовки. И лучше бы это указать.
**Аспирантура: профиль подготовки "Политические институты и процессы, международные отношения"**.

Ну или уточните свой вопрос, а то он чересчур туманный.